# How to upgrade pip in cmd?

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I'm trying to install NumPy in cmd. Numpy has been installed but a warning to upgrade the pip version appears i,e

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I used "upgrade pip"  command but it didn't work i,e

```
C:\Users\test>pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (22.0.4)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-22.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 2.1/2.1 MB 54.0 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 22.0.4
    Uninstalling pip-22.0.4:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-22.0.4
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-lma6z9il\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Comment: Read the last line of the output!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+upgrade+pip+OSError%3A+WinError+5+Access+is+denied

Comment: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

Try this command.

```
C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip --user
```